# JavaFX: adding access role support in FXML without subclassing the control

Tags: javafx, fxml

I use a security subsystem to control user access rights. (My question may not depend on which one, so let's only suppose that there is a method on controller (Java) side, which could tell whether the current user has a given permission or not.)

I would like to control the behaviour and accessibility of some of the controls on the form in FXML-level. Something like this:

```
<Button ... disable="$controller.hasNotPermission" permission="permissionCode">
```

or

```
<Text ... visible="$controller.hasPermission" permission="permissionCode">
```

where the controller's `has(Not)Permission` method would get the permission property value from the caller control and checks it against the user roles.

The trivial way would be to create my own controls (PermissionControlledButton, PermissionControlledText, etc.), and adding this property and support function to them. The problem with this approach is the need to subclassing several dozens of control classes and to add the same code (even if it is only a few lines) to all of them.

Also a possible way would be to move this logic to the `initilaize` method of my controller and bind them there.

However, I am courious if there is any way to **keep this information on FXML level and avoid subclassing**?

Comment: How about using `userData` on your controls ?

Comment: Using userData solves half of my problem: I can now pass the permission to the controller. What I cannot know if I can call a method (instead of referencing a property) within the FXML code. I mean, writing something like this: `<Button ... disable="$controller.hasNotPermission"`, and if I can call methods, how can I aquire within the method the caller control?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot specify dynamic values in `FXML`, to implement this, you need to overrload the `initialize()` in your controller, access the fxml components and alter their property

Comment: Finally I was followed this approach.

Comment: I moved the configuration to the controller level and doing it in the initialize method.
In my case, it is even more secure, because moving the permission assignment to the fxml side would expose it in a plain text file within the JAR and could be tempered much easier than a reverse engineered compiled code would be. :-)

Comment: @Balage1551 I am trying to do something similar to what you did but this is my approach where I am still stuck. Would you be in a position to help on this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270442/how-to-set-a-menu-items-setvisible-property-to-false-in-javafx-8